# how to display user comments by role and user id in drupal 7 views

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, view

I have a list of nodes. Under each node I have opened up commenting. Normal users can comment, special users can respond to the comments.

I want a normal user to see only their comments when viewing such a node AND the responses by the special roles.

I have been experimenting with views but using either a filter or contextual argument of current user:uid only shows the comments by the user, leaving out the responses by admin/editors, etc :(

Appreciate any pointers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to user logic similar to comment_uid = current_uid OR comment_users_role = special_role.

The problem here is that it is hard to use OR logic with contextual filters. [This post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32019/how-to-use-a-views-contextual-filter-or) is discussing the topic and the chosen answers points to [this page](https://drupal.org/node/357082) which has a patch that allows you to pass the value from the contextual filter to the "normal filter".

That is certainly one path to explore, another option would be to user hook_views_query_alter to manually change your query before it is executed. For an example of how to do that see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13531828/drupal-7-views-contextual-filters-or-logic).