# Drupal 7 Views contextual filters OR logic

Tags: drupal, view

Contextual filters are applied in AND logic. Is there any way to have two or more contextual filters in OR logic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In views 7.x-3.5 this may not be possible using the UI.

Assume your module name is `my_module`

Add the following to your my_module.module file

```
<?php
function my_moudle_views_api() {
  return array(
    'api' => 3,
  );
}
?>
```

and

the following to my_module.views.inc

```
<?php
function eb_mine_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->name == 'statuser') {
    dsm($query, 'before');
    $query->where[0]['type'] = 'OR';
    dsm($query, 'after');
  }
}
?>
```

Source : http://drupal.org/node/1451218#comment-6136692

Whereas in the earlier version of views, the AND/OR option of the contextual filter would be decided by that of the first group of static filters in the view.

```
Grouping of contextual filters
Even though contextual filters do not appear in the "and/or" user interface for sorting and grouping regular filters, contextual filters are always added to the first group of filters. Thus the order of the groups can cause the contextual filter to have entirely different effects on the results of a view that has contextual filters. Even though differences might not be apparent through the user interface.

Multiple contextual filters are therefore always in the same "and/or" group of filters, and can not be placed in different groups. There is an effort to add this feature.
```

Comment: I had to renable my module to include the inc file. I also tried hook_views_pre_execute with no success

Comment: This worked for me! I had to do an extra step, though, which I put into a new comment on that linked issue. I hope the Views folks add OR grouping for Contextual Filters soon.

Comment: You may want to point out where this came from... https://drupal.org/comment/6136692#comment-6136692

Comment: You have a typo, bro. It's my_module.views.inc not my_module.view.inc

Answer (score 0):

This is a patch to allow "passing the argument into normal filter [UI]"
https://drupal.org/node/357082

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on having a UI option only, then this module will do the trick.  I've tested it and, although there does seem to be the potential for issues, it is regularly maintained. It didn't seem to break anything when I installed it on my custom Drupal distribution (although I did modify the code a bit to eliminate the possibility of some issues arising with my custom code).

https://www.drupal.org/project/views_contextual_filters_or

Also, the code itself is easy to export to your own module should you wish to isolate the behaviour of this module even further (so that it only applies to specific views, or views that apply to specific content types).